# Dart boolean stays the same after update

Tags: json, rest, flutter, dart

I have a login page where the user credentials checks against a status response from a api. I've written a function that returns a future boolean from the check but my problem is that if the user puts the wrong info the first time all the times they try to log in after the function still comes back as false.

I've print the user input to the console and it shows that the old info was updated but still comes back as false.
Future boolean function:

```
bool loginCheck;
Future<bool>check() async{
try{
await fetchResponse().then((response){
if(response.status == "ok"){
return loginCheck = true;
}else {
  return loginCheck = false;
}
});
    }
    catch (e){
      print(e);
    }
    return loginCheck;
}
```

API response function:

```
Future <SubsonicResponse>fetchResponse() async{
  try{
userClear();    
loginUser();
var authresponse = await http.get(authURL);
if (authresponse.statusCode == 200){
var jsondata = jsonDecode(authresponse.body);
var data = apicallFromJson(jsondata);
var response = data.subsonicResponse;
return response;
} else{
}
}
 catch (e){
    print(e);
    }
}
```

other functions:

```
void loginUser() {
serveraddress = _serveraddressController.text;
password = _passwordController.text;
username = _usernameController.text;
print(username);
print(password);
print(serveraddress);
}

void loginclear(){
_serveraddressController.clear();
_passwordController.clear();
_usernameController.clear();
}

void userClear(){
  loginCheck = null;
  serveraddress = null;
  password = null;
  username = null;
}
```

as you can see above I've tried clearing the user input vars before the request and it updates to the newest user input but still comes back false
Login button:

```
              onPressed: () {
              check().then((loginCheck){
              print(loginCheck);
              if(loginCheck == true){
              loginclear();
              return Get.toNamed('/home');
              } else {
              return showAlertDialog(context);
            }
          });
        },
```

If the user puts the right info in the first time it works no problem.

Comment: Your check() method is rather odd. You are combining async/await with .then calls. Consider switching it to use a [completer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Completer-class.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the state of your variables using some sort of state management, i.e. Use setState() (or streams or what ever based on your use case) to update your variable.

Simply calling user clear will not work.

Comment: so i found out my problem, the even though the text string values update the string url doesn't update, i've tried putting the url string into the future function but it still doesnt update. Its suppose to take the user input and inject it into the url. Can you give me an idea on how i would set state for the url?